# BlackBerry® Device Simulators v5.0.0.713 (9550) is not launching

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I keep getting this error:

> Catastrophic assertion failure

When I try starting the simulator (BlackBerry® Device Simulators v5.0.0.713 (9550)), am using BlackBerry Theme Studio 6.0. What can I do?

Comment: You can install another simulator, or reset it (look for the "clean.bat" file in the sim folder). If you reset, everything you have installed will be erased.